# Maven Setup on LAN

Tags: java, maven

I wan to use vmmagent-0.6.5 jar file. vmmagent is maven project and depends on many other jar files.. I want to setup Maven project localy and use this jar file for reference files 
[Vmmagent maven code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ow2.jasmine/vmmagent/0.6.5/)
is this possible to setup this project localy or i have to connect through internet for connection purpose because i see this line in pom.xml file

```
<scm>
<connection>
scm:svn:svn://svn.forge.objectweb.org/svnroot/jasmine/jasmine-vm/vmm-agent/tags/vmmagent-0.6.5
</connection>
<developerConnection>
scm:svn:svn+ssh://dangtran@svn.forge.objectweb.org/svnroot/jasmine/jasmine-vm/vmm-agent/tags/vmmagent-0.6.5
</developerConnection>
<url>
http://fisheye.jasmine.objectweb.org/browse/JASMINe/jasmine/jasmine-vm/vmm-agent/tags/vmmagent-0.6.5
</url>
</scm>
```

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup maven client to use the proxy server , go to settings.xml of maven directory

and place this-

```
<settings>  <proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>genproxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>theipofserver</host>
  <port>port</port>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>password</password>
</proxy>
```

Regards
Anshul